# c# check if class exists at compiler time

Tags: c#, preprocessor, conditional-compilation

For 2 different topics ('Sound Management' and 'Multilingual support'), I have created 2 different modules.

Since there are 2 very different topics, and in other projects probably only the one or the other module can be needed, I want them to run 'for themselves'. So that they can also be run independently of each other.

But now I have the situation that the SoundManager has to load either Sound A or Sound B depending on the language. So a small overlap of the functionality.

Here is a simplified representation of the program logic:

```
public class i18n {
    public static AudioClip LoadAudioClip(string localizationID) {
        return Resources.Load<AudioClip>(LoadString(localizationID));
    }
}


// And in another .cs file

public class SoundManager {
    PreparePlay(int catNr, int clipNr) {
        audioSource.clip = audioCategorie[catNr].clipList[clipNr].audioClip;
        if(audioSource.clip == null) {
            #if (How can I test here if the other class exists?)  !!!!!!!!!!!
            audioSource.clip = i18n.LoadAudioClip(audioCategorie[catNr].clipList[clipNr].clipID);
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What other class you are looking for? What is the class you are getting right now? In what case you have different class? What issue you will face if you don't know the other class ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "modules". Perhaps you could derive i18n from an interface known to SoundManager and register the implementation during initialization in the SoundManager class?